# Get time in London no matter of local time

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

is there any way how to get London time in javascript no matter of local timezone offset? Futhermore I need to be able to work with a result in same way as Date() object.

I am able to get London time as a string with moment/moment-timezone (e.g. "2018-01-26T17:59:00Z"). Putting result to new Date() function leads to having a local time:

```
new Date(moment().tz('Europe/London').format())
// results getting my local time, instead I need to get London time
```

Comment: `Date` isn't local time, it's *represented* as local when you output it.

Comment: What is so "bad" about the moment version (`moment().tz('Europe/London')`) ?

Comment: @Andreas because it return string, I need to be able to get day, hours and minutes from it, same as with Date() object. String is useless for me.

Comment: Then just remove `.format()` O.o

Comment: See dup marked, and also [this dup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33579806/634824).

Comment: As far as getting day, hours, minutes, etc. - then don't call `.format()`, but call the relevant functions on the moment object.

Comment: (Oh, and not super important, but it's more "correct" to use `moment.tz(...)` rather than `moment().tz(...)` for this use case.)